# How to show 'loading' before all async requests done?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react hooks in my project and I want to show text 'loading' until I get a response from all requests in current page. How to do this?

Comment: You will find several answers here on stack overflow on how to wait for all the async requests you are making and to show a loading text you can just a `if-else` or a `ternary` condition and return `loading`  from your component when your requests are still pending or return the actual data when everything is finished loading.

You can control the `loading` parameter by storing it in the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this but here is one pattern I tend to use:

```
const ComponentMakingApiCall = () => {
  const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post({
      // whatever request you are making
    }).then(response => {
      setIsLoading(false)
    })
  },[])
  
  if (isLoading){
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        // render some content
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If you have multiple requests, you could do something like this:

```
const ComponentMakingApiCall = () => {
  const [ requestALoading, setRequestALoading ] = useState(true)
  const [ requestBLoading, setRequestBLoading ] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post({
      // request A
    }).then(response => {
      handleResponse(response)
      setRequestALoading(false)
    })
  },[])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post({
      // request B
    }).then(response => {
      handleResponse(response)
     setRequestBLoading(false)
    })
    
  },[])

  if ( requestALoading || requestBLoading ) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        // render some content
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

async () => {
  setIsLoading(true)

  // your codes (fetch API, try/catch, etc)

  setIsLoading(false)
}

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {isLoading && <LoadingComponentUI />}
    {!isLoading && yourCondition && (
      <YourComponent />
    )}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```